# Iterator hasNext means list is never empty

Tags: java, iterator

I just have a quick question about iterators.

I currently want to remove items that are duplicates from two lists of objects.

The way I have it set up right now is that as long as the second list (the list of objects that need to be removed from the first list) has items, the loop which has does the merging will keep on running.

I have been using the `hasNext()` function to check if there are still items but I think there may be a slight problem with that.

When the iterator is pointing at the last item in the list and calls `hasNext()`, it will return false since there is nothing after the last item. This means that the item won't be removed from the first list. Is that true?

Here's the code:

```
for (Iterator<Card> discardItr = discard.iterator(); discardItr.hasNext();)
{
    Card tempDiscard = discardItr.next();

    Iterator<Card> mixedItr = mixedHand.iterator();
    while (mixedItr.hasNext())
    {
        if (tempDiscard.equals(mixedItr.next()))
        {
            discardItr.remove();
            mixedItr.remove();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `hasNext()` is true if and only if a subsequent call to `next()` will succeed.

Comment: Does this mean that even if there is one item left in this list, it will return true? 
For example. [1,2,3]
Would it return true even at the last item 3?

Comment: What do you think, will `next()` give you the last element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Iterator` will loop over the whole list, even when you call `iterator#remove`. For example running

```
public class IteratorDemo {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(  );
    list.addAll( Arrays.asList("first", "second", "third" ) );
    Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
      String next = iterator.next();
      System.out.println(next);
      iterator.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

produces the following output

```
first
second
third
```

So your code will work (which you would of course have discovered by just trying it)

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is small, and you can use `Set` instead of `List`, you can use following code, which is much simpler and cleaner, but needs more memory:

```
Set<Card> discardCopy = new HashSet<Card>(discard);
Set<Card> mixedCopy = new HashSet<Card>(mixedHand);
mixedHand.removeAll(discardCopy);
discard.removeAll(mixedCopy);
```